# How do I make a specific letter of a string uppercase in Julia?

Tags: string, julia, uppercase

How do I make a specific letter of a string uppercase, and not changing any of the other letters?

My example:

```
"this works" -> "this woRks" //Change made to letter 7
"this works" -> "this wOrks" //Change made to letter 6
"this works" -> "This works" //Change made to letter 1
```

My system uses characters with a UTF-8 encoding, so it needs to support uppercase for UTF-8 characters and not just ascii.

Comment: you could also use MutableStrings

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Would that work with the Swedish lower case å ä ö  and upper case Å Ä Ö ?

Comment: hm, apologies, I've tested the MutableStrings package and it seems to be deprecated. Best to go with the list comprehension one-liner Oliver described below, possibly packaged into a nice little function. that's what I would have suggested first as well. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unoptimized one-liner :)

```
julia> s = "this is a lowercase string"
"this is a lowercase string"

julia> String([i == 4 ? uppercase(c) : c for (i, c) in enumerate(s)])
"thiS is a lowercase string"
```

Comment: nice solution, probably enough in most cases.

Comment: What about non ASCII characters?

Comment: This will work good on all characters as this is an equivalent of my `IOBuffer` code (probably a bit slower, but one-liner).

Answer (score 6):

### This is how can you do it with slicing a string:

#### In Julia 0.6

```
function uppercasen(s::AbstractString, i::Int)
    0 < i <= length(s) || error("index $i out of range")
    pos =  chr2ind(s, i)
    string(s[1:prevind(s, pos)], uppercase(s[pos]), s[nextind(s, pos):end])
end

for i in 1:3
    println(uppercasen("kół", i))
end
```

#### In Julia 0.7 (here I use `SubString` as it will be a bit faster than using `String` - similar thing can be done in Julia 0.6)

```
function uppercasen(s::AbstractString, i::Int)
    0 < i <= length(s) || error("index $i out of range")
    pos =  nextind(s, 0, i)
    string(SubString(s, 1, prevind(s, pos)), uppercase(s[pos]), SubString(s, nextind(s, pos)))
end

for i in 1:3
    println(uppercasen("kół", i))
end
```

### However, the code below should work under both versions of Julia (unfortunately it is slower):

```
function uppercasen(s::AbstractString, i::Int)
    0 < i <= length(s) || error("index $i out of range")
    io = IOBuffer()
    for (j, c) in enumerate(s)
        write(io, i == j ? uppercase(c) : c)
    end
    String(take!(io))
end
```

Comment: I have edited the answer. Unfortunately collecting an `IOBuffer` in this case benchmarks slower (probably the code could be optimized; I leave this as an example as sometimes it is useful to use `IOBuffer`). The other change I have made is replacing `String` slicing by `SubString` in Julia 0.7 case - as this benchmarks to be a bit faster.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another snippet if you're working with simple ASCII strings:

```julia
toupper(x, i) = x[1:i-1] * uppercase(x[i:i]) * x[i+1:end]
```

```julia
julia> toupper("this works", 1)
"This works"

julia> toupper("this works", 4)
"thiS works"

julia> toupper("this works", 7)
"this wOrks"
```

A slight advantage of this approach is that it can be trivially adapted as

```julia
`toupper(x, i, j) = x[1:i-1] * uppercase(x[i:j]) * x[j+1:end]`
```

to convert to uppercase a *range* within the string as opposed to a single letter.

Comment: (obviously, Oliver's solution can be trivially adapted in the same way too though, e.g. `i in a_range ? uppercase(c) ... ` etc )

Comment: Unfortunately this will work only for ASCII, and fail for general UTF-8. Check out: `toupper("Kół", 2)`. That is why in my answer you need to use `nextind` and `prevind`.

Comment: I would say that this is one of the trickiest parts of Base Julia. Even in Base there were several bugs because of this problem. I vote up for your answer, because it should stay as a warning I think - but can you update it so that it is clear that it is valid only for ASCII?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I guess this is the case for the swedish lower case  åäö and upper case ÅÄÖ

Comment: Exactly. You can check the length of encoding of a given letter using `Base.codelen` function (it is not exported, so you should not relay on it in production code, but it is good enough for interactive work). If `codelen` is greater than 1 then it is not ASCII and you will have a problem.